# Android LiveData order of observation

Tags: android-livedata

I have a `LiveData` and, say, *n* `Observer`s of it. One of the `Observer`s, call it `o`, updates global state, upon which the other *n-1* `Observer`s depend.

Is there any way to guarantee that `o` is executed first? Is it merely that `o` be added first?

I've looked through the relevant docs and see nothing mentioned explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically there's no specific guarantee declared that I'm aware of.

Practically as long as all of your observers are added using the same `lifecycleOwner` they should be invoked in registration order as `LiveData` internally uses forward iteration ([source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-lifecycle-release/lifecycle/lifecycle-livedata-core/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData.java#147)) to update them.